# Why v4l recommends against using header supplied by kernel?

Tags: linux, header-files, v4l2

The [Video4Linux documentation](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/func-ioctl.html) says:

> Macros and defines specifying V4L2 ioctl requests are located in the videodev2.h header file. Applications should use their own copy, not include the version in the kernel sources on the system they compile on.

So, should I copy this file from `/usr/include/linux/videodev2.h` to my project folder or what?
And if yes, why?

Answer (score 2):

That is what they are asking you to do.

On the why, you'd have to ask the developers.

If you have got the package(s) as part of your distribution, you should use what your distribution suggests. Read the documentation for what you have installed, and make sure any external recomendations are for your distribution and version.

Answer (score 0):

i think what they mean is, that you should *not* use the headers in `LINUXSOURCETREE/include/linux/videodev2.h`

i would suggest to always use headers installed in `/usr/include/` rather than shipping headers on your own, which might have nothing to do with the actual system....